# GDB permission issue, trying to debug called function

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, fuse

I am writing a cache sytem in fuse (HW assigment) and debugging it with gdb.
im having a problem instructing gdb to add a break point in one of my function that is not part of my executable file.

im using gdb with the following script, where CachingFileSystem is where the main function is, and Cache.o is the file where the function I would like to debug:

```
exec CachingFileSystem
file Cache.o
break Cache::readFromBlock(Block *, off_t, size_t,char *)
run /tmp/r /tmp/m 10 0.4 0.4
```

gdb adds the break point correctly -

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x267b: file Cache.cpp, line 377.
```

but when running I get:

```
(gdb)     run /tmp/r /tmp/m 10 0.4 0.4
'ex4/Cache.o' has changed; re-reading symbols.
Starting program: ex4/Cache.o /tmp/r /tmp/m 10 0.4 0.4
ex4/Cache.o: Permission denied.
During startup program exited with code 1.
```

Debuuging the main program, CachingFileSystem,  works as expected without any problems.

Comment: You should probably use `add-symbol-file Cache.o` instead of `file Cache.o`, but could you tell us more about the runtime structure of your program? Is `Cache` located in a dynamically loaded object?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i'll try that. how do i get the required addrees of my file?
Cache it not dynamically loaded, but just a file I compile and link normally.

Comment: Try using `file CachingFileSystem` instead of `exec CachingFileSystem`. That will load the symbol table for all the linked-in components and you probably won't need to use any additional  file or symbol table commands.